# move to the next row below even upon a datagrid refresh

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have this code below which upon click it changes the default value for the Progress column from 0 to 1. The problem am having is that upon clicking the datagrid is also refreshed. I want it to be refreshed but I want to stay where it is and move to the next row below it. Upon refresh the cursor goes back to the beginning as expected. Yes I know it is obvious is because I call the refreshDataGrid function at the end so it will always do that.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString2 = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
        string query2 = "UPDATE dbo.[" + comboBox4.Text + "] SET Progress= '1' where code = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'; ";


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);

            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Connection.Close();

        }

        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        comboBox3.ResetText();
        comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1;


        if (dataGridView3.CurrentRow != null)
            dataGridView3.CurrentCell =
                dataGridView3.Rows[Math.Min(dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Index + 1, dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1)]
                .Cells[dataGridView3.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
        refreshDataGrid();}
```

I was hoping this particular block of code would solve the problem:

```
 if (dataGridView3.CurrentRow != null)
            dataGridView3.CurrentCell =
                dataGridView3.Rows[Math.Min(dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Index + 1, dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1)]
                .Cells[dataGridView3.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
```

What I was trying to do is capture the current position of the highlighted row index and no matter if I call the refreshDataGrid function, it would still move in sequence rather than starting from the beginning each time.
Is there a way to accomplish this? To explain once more, I want to keep the current highlighted row index and let it move to the one following without having to worry about starting over upon refresh. eg. if I start at row 1 then it would go to row two even if I call the refreshDataGrid function.

Comment: use updatepanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. 
stored the current row index to a variable and then incremented that value:

```
                var i = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Index;
                refreshDataGrid();
                dataGridView3.CurrentCell = dataGridView3.Rows[Math.Min(i + 1, dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1)].Cells[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the current cell selection before refreshing the grid, then reset it after refreshing the grid completes.  Depending on how the refresh works, you can save row and column position  or save some key values to find the row again if the order or count might change.

```
        if (dataGridView3.CurrentRow != null)
            SaveCurrentCellLocation();

        refreshDataGrid();

        ResetCurrentCellLocation();
```

Comment: Tried that, No improvement

Comment: Skips to the next row but freezes after

Comment: Setting cell selection should not freeze the UI, probably more going on here.  Is refreshDataGrid() Sync or Async?

Comment: No not freezing the UI, i mean the application still works but it doesn't move to the other rows

Comment: ResetCurrentCellLocation is probably poorly named. This is where you should be doing the n+1 logic